# Transform a Cermine JATS XML in R

Tags: java, r, xml, pdf

I try to figure out how to parse the XML file created by [Cermine](https://github.com/CeON/CERMINE).
First of all I have build the java calls into R

```
path <- "C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/pdf"
file <- "C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/pdf/file.pdf"

        ContentExtractor <- function(path){
          command = paste("java -cp cermine-impl-1.13-jar-with-dependencies.jar pl.edu.icm.cermine.ContentExtractor -outputs","jats","-path", path)
          system(command)
        }

        CRFBibReferenceParser <- function(reference){
          command = paste("java -cp cermine-impl-1.13-jar-with-dependencies.jar pl.edu.icm.cermine.bibref.CRFBibReferenceParser -reference", reference)
          system(command)
        }

        CRFAffiliationParser <- function(affiliation){
          command = paste("java -cp cermine-impl-1.13-jar-with-dependencies.jar pl.edu.icm.cermine.metadata.affiliation.CRFBibReferenceParser -affiliation", affiliation)
          system(command)
        }

        ContentExtractorSingle <- function(file){
          filename <- basename(file)
          file.copy(from = file, to = paste0(tempdir(),"\\",filename))
          command = paste("java -cp cermine-impl-1.13-jar-with-dependencies.jar pl.edu.icm.cermine.ContentExtractor -outputs","jats","-path", tempdir())
          system(command)

          ##### the XML parsing will be placed in here
        }
```

Samples of how the data looks after the Cermine has transformed the pdf to a .cermxml can be found here:

**Samples:**
https://jats.nlm.nih.gov/publishing/tag-library/1.0/

https://jats.nlm.nih.gov/publishing/tag-library/1.0/FullArticleSamples/bmj_sample.xml
https://jats.nlm.nih.gov/publishing/tag-library/1.0/FullArticleSamples/pnas_sample.xml

What i have already tried are different approaches e.g.:

```
library(XML)
library(plyr)
library(tools)
xmlfile <- xmlParse(paste0(tempdir(),"\\",file_path_sans_ext(filename),".cermxml"))
test <- ldply(xmlToList(xmlfile), as.data.frame)
```

Which did not work.

```
xtree <- xmlInternalTreeParse(paste0(tempdir(),"\\",file_path_sans_ext(filename),".cermxml"), options = DTDLOAD)
root <- xmlRoot(xtree)
xpathApply(root,"//year",xmlValue)
```

This successfully retrieves the Year from al the references. I can not go one node higher because the result will be a character and will not keep the structure.
Another problem with the above code is that for papers with multiple authors in the references, i get e.g. 12 autors but with only 5 years. Hence, even when trying to extract the information this way it will not be possible to get everythin into a nice table.

Same problem occures obviously with this code:

```
as.data.frame(xpathSApply(root,"//year",function(x) xmlSApply(x,xmlValue)))
as.data.frame(t(xpathSApply(root,"//year",function(x) xmlSApply(x,xmlValue))))
```

Now the question:
How can I transform the XML data to a usable data frame for the references and the pdf metadata?
(I'm not intrested in the main content of the pdf because there are better tools than cermine to extract the pure pdf text)